# How to make encryption in hdfs?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am currently using hadoop-2.7.3 I configured this for multiple clustering. Now I want to add Encryption system for hdfs. In that,

I changed core-site.xml file as,
hadoop.security.key.provider.path=kms://http@master:16000/kms

I can create a key and directory successfully.

But I can't create Encryption Zone.

When I lookup into kms-audit.log file, It shows

```
UNAUTHENTICATED RemoteHost:<machine ip> Method:OPTIONS URL:http://master:16000/kms/v1/keys ErrorMsg:'Authentication required'
```

In terminal I am getting error like,

```
RemoteException: Can't create an encryption zone for /zone since no key provider is available.
```

I am confused with this error Please help me sort out this problem.

Comment: Please follow this https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/TransparentEncryption.html

Comment: I followed that same commands, in that documentation. but, I am still facing problem